# Oracle recreate package from .sql file

Tags: sql, oracle

For version control purposes, every time I modify something in any of my packages, I click in the save spec package and body option and export it as .sql to my local repository. However, I'm not sure on how to recreate the package from that file (in case something went wrong with the latest version and I need to rollback changes).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load (or copy/paste its contents) it into SQL Editor and run it as a script. Package specification first, body next.